# command to view user rights and the owner of a file or document via windows cmd

Tags: novell

I have got a novell file share and I am wanting to find out the permissions of the fileshare in the windows cmd. I was just wondering what commands I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

SYS:PUBLIC\RIGHTS.EXE

Available on any server Novell, OES or Netware - it does not matter.